# VB making a progress bar go up automatically whilst the program checks a database

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I'm new to coding but when my program checks a database it takes a long time. My client wants a progress bar which goes up as the program runs through the code so he can see how long he has to wait.

I tried adding this code into the program in random places "
    ProgressBar.Value += 10" however it didn't get the affect I wanted.

How do I create a progress bar which automatically goes up based on how far the program is through the code?

Comment: I would start with googling "vba progress bar".  Have you done anything so far?

Comment: VB.NET and VBA are not the same. Which is it?

Comment: In order to increment a `ProgressBar` accurately you must first determine how many operations you have to do, then you determine how much you should increment by for each completed operation.

Comment: Why not look into making the program **not**  take a long time?

Comment: You also don't need the [visual-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) tag as although you may code in that your question is not specific to that. Tags go a long way to getting you a suitable answer.

Comment: @Jinx88909 Sorry I am new to coding I wasn't aware, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry im new to coding, my program had to read in a lot of data from multiple database tables so I thought it'd be cool to have a progress bar.

Comment: @VisualVincent its Visual Basic Studio progject written in a windows form

Comment: @tompreston I did some googling however I didn't understand it compared to my code, I tried to implement what other users were doing but it kept giving me error messages.

Comment: @rwan, In the nicest possible way, you haven't posted your code here, how can you expect us to help you with your specific code if you haven't posted it?  The constructive thing to do is to try a solution, get the error message, research, then come back here if you're stuck (with the error message, and your code, and the correct tag- VBA or vb.net, it is not both).  Good luck.

Comment: `I thought it'd be cool to...`  A phrase that has justified the cost of employing/contracting many cat-herders.  If you cant increment after each of the many tables has loaded, use Marquee style.  You still have conflicting tags on the post: hold the mouse over them to read the usage guidance and remove the one that does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ProgressBar.Min to Zero, and ProgressBar.Max to the number of records that need processing.
Then for each loop, add one to ProgressBar.Value.

Finally, if the display is not updating, it's because the database operation is not giving the CPU a chance to re-draw the progress bar with the new value.

If you want to re-paint the progress bar, call the Refresh() function of the control you want to re-paint or the form containing it. - thx to @Steven in the comments for this.

Comment: As Plutonix said, you should try to work out why it's taking so long and improve that.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, I'll try and implement this. I think the Application.DoEvents can resolve my issue.

Comment: @rwan Every time you use `Application.DoEvents` a puppy dies.

Comment: Never ever ever use `DoEvents()`. It is evil incarnate and it will introduce insidious bugs into your code.

Comment: Do NOT use Application.DoEvents! That will slow your process down considerably and is the most over-used and misunderstood function I have ever come across.

If you want to re-paint the progress bar, call the Refresh() function of the control you want to re-paint or the form containing it. Calling this function on the form forces the form and all of the controls on it to re-paint. This has far less cost than the Application.DoEvents() function.